# Property is not set for per machine installation via UI

Tags: .net, wix

I need to parse the property "INSTALLEDUSING" to the custom action and there to save it to app.config. It works for per user installation both from cmd or ui, but when I install per machine via ui seems not to work, I tried to installed per machine from cmd by setting ALLUSERS="1" and it works. So I will add the code that I used for this:

```
  <Property Id="INSTALLEDUSING" Secure="yes" Value="msi"/>

   <Fragment>
      <CustomAction Id="SaveInstalledUsing" BinaryKey="OfficePlatform" DllEntry="SaveInstalledUsingParameter" Return="check"/>
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
         <Custom Action="SaveInstalledUsing" After="InstallFinalize">((NOT Installed) OR (UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE)) AND (NOT ( REMOVE="ALL"))</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

This property indicates me if the installation was run through .exe or .msi installer. Why the UI per machine installation doesn't set this property and it returns empty string?

Comment: Could you update your question to clarify these things: Do you mean that you run the custom action while a dialog is shown, and there's a control referencing `INSTALLEDUSING` that doesn't update? What does a verbose log show for updates to the `INSTALLEDUSING` property, and when do they occur, relative to the UI you expect to see it in?

Comment: @MichaelUrman I updated the question trying to explain exactly my issue. Is it more clear now? Any suggestions how to solve it?

Comment: Try using Type 51 Custom Action '<SetProperty Id="SaveInstalledUsing"  After="CostFinalize" Value="[INSTALLEDUSING]">IfAnyConditions</SetProperty>'. The Id should match your CustomAction Id which requires the Property.

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work, but I found which is the problem..Seems that is a privileges problem, because when I run with administrator it works...